# How to prefer package-local class over library class's inner class?

Tags: java

Given this code:

```
package my.pkg;

import com.google.common.util.concurrent.Service;

class Test implements Service {
  public static void main(String... a) {
    System.out.println(Listener.class);
  }

  // method implementations omitted for brevity
}
```

And given there's one `Listener` class in `my.pkg`, and one as an inner class in the `Service` class I'm importing.

I would expect the package local class to 'win' here, since I'm not referring to `Service.Listener.class` or explicitly importing the inner class. Apparently, IntelliJ expects the same thing, since if I explicitly add `import my.pkg.Listener;`, it is automatically removed as being redundant. However, when compiling and running this code (Gradle 2.14.1 and openjdk 1.8.0_91, if that matters), it's very clear the inner class is winning.

How do I get this code to use the class in `my.pkg`? Explicitly adding the import doesn't work, since my IDE removes it. I'd also prefer not to use full class names (`my.pkg.Listener`) everywhere in the class.

Comment: You should be able to use both of them if you do not import the inner Listener from Service.
Listener should refer to you local class, while Service.Listener should refer to the inner one.

Comment: As stated in the question, I already don't import the `Listener` from `Service`, just `Service` itself.

Comment: Then it should not result in the conflict.

Comment: That's what I expected too. And still, it does.

Comment: Could you please paste the output from your OpenJDK run?

Comment: In eclipse, it prints "class my.pkg.Listener"

Comment: Oh ffs, of course there's a difference between the example and the actual code. In this case, in the actual code `Test` implements `Service`. I'll update the question.

Comment: Does the class in your package really have to be called `Listener` ?

Comment: Now at least I understand why this is happening, but it's still not what I'd expect to happen.

Comment: @Berger naming is hard ;)